# How to create table using query in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

I am developing windows phone app.  I have searched and find the solution of database connectivity.  But it shows database connecting using context class and linq without sql query.

Is it possible to write pure sql query? Ex. "create table emp(eid int, ename varchar(45))".

Any one assist me to handle the logic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you use SQL Server Compact you can only add tables and columns via your LINQ to SQL classes, no raw SQL access is possible.

Have you looked at the DatabaseSchemaUpdater class?

One possible solution may be to use SQLite.